# GDAL to convert GML to KML

Tags: gdal, kml, ogr2ogr, gml

I have a GML file and it has a code structure as follows. When I convert it to KML via GDAL, it does not read the coordinates. When I delete negative values, it reads but only one position appears. How can I fix it?

```
    <gml:segments>
      <gml:GeodesicString>
        <gml:posList>54.33333333 -26.48555556 54.33777778 -26.45777778</gml:posList>
      </gml:GeodesicString>
    </gml:segments>
```

Comment: Your GML contains geometry that is of type GeodesicString http://www.datypic.com/sc/niem21/e-gml32_GeodesicString.html but GDAL does not support it https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gml.html. The KML format does not support geodesic strings either. You must approximate the geodetic string into some supported format. Unfortunately GDAL does not have methods for that.

Comment: I have example like this, but I can display it properly. Normally, there are more coordinates in the postList tag

 <aixm:ElevatedCurve gml:id="uuid.26f72e39-8d6d-4244-b931-52b1d779f7f2" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326">
 <gml:segments>
<gml:GeodesicString interpolation="geodesic">
<gml:posList>50.10347116 14.24986137 50.10343927 14.24992872</gml:posList>
</gml:GeodesicString>
</gml:segments>
<aixm:horizontalAccuracy uom="M">0.5</aixm:horizontalAccuracy>
 <aixm:elevation uom="M">376</aixm:elevation>
<aixm:verticalAccuracy uom="M">0.5</aixm:verticalAccuracy>
</aixm:ElevatedCurve>

Comment: If you mean that `<gml:posList>50.10347116 14.24986137 50.10343927 14.24992872</gml:posList>` is OK for GDAL but `<gml:posList>54.33333333 -26.48555556 54.33777778 -26.45777778</gml:posList>` not then I must be on a wrong track and my previous comment can be ignored.

Comment: The data I mentioned in the question is incorrectly converted to the kml file, but the data I mentioned in the comment is converted correctly. Both data have the same labels.

Comment: What if you add the interpolation attribute `<gml:GeodesicString interpolation="geodesic">`? That's the only difference that I notice.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work, but when I change the signs of the longitude coordinates, it takes me to a wrong place on the map.

Comment: Certainly the sign matters. Is the geometry correct when the route has just positive longitudes, so eastwards from Greenwich?

Comment: But when I don't change the signs, GDAL cannot get the coordinates. How can I fix this

Comment: I try to make you first confirm that everything works correctly when longitudes are positive. A complete test dataset is GML would be appreciated.

Comment: When longitudes are positive, they point to the wrong area on a wrong line. When the longitudes are negative, I cannot see the coordinates in the kml file. I use og2ogr

Comment: I speak on a general level. Does it go right from Bremen to Hannover https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=7/52.736/9.256 with the corresponding coordinates, which naturally have positive longitudes.

Comment: When I take the coordinates as positive values, it shows the point in this [link](https://maps.app.goo.gl/3zsC1yPHY1z8tNYF6)